# Catch on throw from contract

Tags: solidity

Is there any built-in way of catching `throw` clauses?

For example, if I'm building a voting application where people must be given permission by the chairperson before voting, otherwise the contract `throw`s.

Would it be possible to catch this `throw` in order to give the user a feedback of what happened without having to manually trigger an event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Throw generates an invalid `JUMP` in the EVM causing immediate termination.

If you're building your own DApp, simply check for voting rights before trying to vote. It's simpler than handling exceptional cases.